# vba choosing biggest value, but only from rows which have certain value in other column

Tags: vba, excel

I have a quite big file (13k rows).
[It looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAaxv.jpg)
I need to figure out a makro which will for each family choose the highest education value among it's members and insert it for all of them in new column.
Any advices how to do it would be very appreciated.

Comment: `=Max(A1:C1)` and copy/drag the formula down.

Comment: It is not my problem. I don't need the highest value of set A1, B1, C1. I need the highest value of C from all rows in which A=x. And i do have circa 5k families to go (so 5k of uniqe A values), each family can have different number of members. But thank you for the response!

Comment: Ah, `=Aggregate(14,6,$C$2:$C$13000/($A$2:$A$13000=A2),1)` in D2 and copy/drag down.

Comment: `{=MAX(IF($A:$A=$A1,$C:$C))}` and drag down - enter using Ctrl+Shift+Enter.  Will give value 5 for family 1 and value 6 for family 2.  Edit:  +1 to @Scott as it doesn't use a CSE formula.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook One should avoid using full column references with array formulas. It will do 1 million more calculations than needed.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook but thanks

Comment: If you have Office 365 Excel you can use: `=MAXIFS(C:C,A:A,A2)` in D2 and copy/drag down.

Comment: Scott Craner, thank you very, very much! I would spend ages to figure it out myself. It works perfectly :)
Darren Bartrup-Cook Thank you very much as well!

Comment: @Scott Craner - good point. Maybe an INDEX/MATCH to get the last row would've been better, but if it's a set amount of rows.  Either way Aggregate is the better function to use.

Answer (score 0):

Put `=MAX(IF(A2=A:A,C:C))` in cell D2, and confirm it as an array formula, then copy that cell down column D. Edit: Beaten to it, and with a better answer, by @Scott Craner in the comments

Comment: One should avoid using full column references with array formulas.  It will do 1 million more calculations than needed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time bobajob